# Question conserning using とかしたら

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, expressions

A character from a book (カゲロウデイズ -in a daze-) said this:

> 「ほら、お揃いのカップでみんなでお茶とかしたら楽しそうじゃない？」

I am confused as to the use of the "とかしたら" after "お茶." She is saying that something seems fun with the uniform's cap, but how is "とかしたら" being used? Is it the "とか" in a list with the -たら from of する, just "と" attached to the verb "かす," or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 〜とかしたら is almost the same as 〜したら。Simply put, it can be said 〜お茶したら楽しそうじゃない？ So why we use とかしたら? 
If we use とかしたら, there are possibilities for other options, while 〜したら explicitly set the condition.

Ex. 
次の週末に旅行したら、リフレッシュできる (If I travel next weekend, I'll get refreshed) 
次の週末に旅行とかしたら、リフレッシュできる (If I do something like travelling, I'll get refreshed) / Here, travelling is not the only way to get refreshed.